# Mongoose - always return null instead of an error when no result found?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Why mongoose always return null instead of an error when no result found?

```
Person.findOne({ 'name': 'Ghost' }, function (err, person) {
  console.log(err); // null
  if (err) return handleError(err);
});
```

The person 'Ghost' does not exist in my db so I am expecting an error but I get null instead. Why? How can get get an error instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because mongoose only return an error when there is an error, not finding any result is not an error. You can handle the response if you got null, like :

```
Person.findOne({ 'name': 'Ghost' }, function (err, person) {
  if(person === null) {
     console.log('No results found');
  }
  if (err) return handleError(err);
});
```

or

```
Person.findOne({ 'name': 'Ghost' }, function (err, person) {    
  if (err) {
     return handleError(err);
  } else if (person) {
     return person;
  } else {
    return 'No results found';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose use `err` for internal errors like failing validation etc. If query complete successfully (with results or not) `err` will contain `null`.

What documentation says:

> Anywhere a callback is passed to a query in Mongoose, the callback
>   follows the pattern `callback(error, results)`. What results is depends
>   on the operation: For `findOne()` it is a potentially-null single
>   document, `find()` a list of documents, `count()` the number of documents,
>   `update()` the number of documents affected, etc. The API docs for
>   Models provide more detail on what is passed to the callbacks.

Comment: Basically this is the same answer as the first one.